# App Activity Crashing

Tags: java, android

This is my first post so please forgive me if I break any rules.

I am in the process of writing an app using ADT and the app keeps crashing when I launch one of my activities through a button press. The activity only started giving me trouble when I made one of the buttons within it run a long and complicated piece of Java. I tested the Java in Netbeans prior to porting it over onto the app and it functioned perfectly. When I first added the code to the src files, ADT rejected it because I used a String Switch, which are only compatible in java 1.7 (I was compiling with 1.6 and my android device has 4.2.2 which only supports 1.6). After re-writing the code without the string switch, the code compiled using 1.6 (Android version 4.3.2) with no errors but once run on the device (Android version 4.2.2 Rooted with HyperDrive Rom) running the activity that ran the Java caused the app to crash.
What code should I post so someone can look over it and find any errors?

EDIT: Okay Guys here's the Log Cat:
`10-26 19:19:27.223: W/ActivityThread(22541): Application com.example.cube can be debugged on port 8100...
10-26 19:19:27.603: D/libEGL(22541): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
10-26 19:19:27.613: D/libEGL(22541): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
10-26 19:19:27.643: D/libEGL(22541): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
10-26 19:19:27.653: I/Adreno200-EGL(22541): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3579225)
10-26 19:19:27.653: I/Adreno200-EGL(22541): Build Date: 04/22/13 Mon
10-26 19:19:27.653: I/Adreno200-EGL(22541): Local Branch: adreno_sba_20130419
10-26 19:19:27.653: I/Adreno200-EGL(22541): Remote Branch: 
10-26 19:19:27.653: I/Adreno200-EGL(22541): Local Patches: 
10-26 19:19:27.653: I/Adreno200-EGL(22541): Reconstruct Branch: 
10-26 19:19:27.963: D/OpenGLRenderer(22541): Enabling debug mode 0
10-26 19:19:29.605: D/GestureDetector(22541): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
10-26 19:19:30.096: E/SpannableStringBuilder(22541): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-26 19:19:30.096: E/SpannableStringBuilder(22541): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-26 19:19:30.956: D/GestureDetector(22541): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 6 mFalseSizeCnt:0
10-26 19:19:31.407: E/SpannableStringBuilder(22541): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-26 19:19:31.407: E/SpannableStringBuilder(22541): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-26 19:19:33.369: D/GestureDetector(22541): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 5 mFalseSizeCnt:0
10-26 19:19:34.250: E/SpannableStringBuilder(22541): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-26 19:19:34.250: E/SpannableStringBuilder(22541): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-26 19:19:35.391: D/GestureDetector(22541): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 8 mFalseSizeCnt:0
10-26 19:19:35.571: D/AndroidRuntime(22541): Shutting down VM
10-26 19:19:35.571: W/dalvikvm(22541): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b906c0)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cube/com.example.cube.AlgorithmConverter}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1886)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at com.example.cube.AlgorithmConverter.<init>(AlgorithmConverter.java:15)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
10-26 19:19:35.591: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    ... 11 more`

I'm sure the XML is sound but the java is lengthy and hard to understand even with comments so I'm hesitant to post it.
Please Help!
**Thanks a Lot!!**

Comment: You should probably post the code of the class that is responsible for the button, and then the XML of the button.

Comment: Or at least some crash log.

Comment: No code for now, just the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: With the log, it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/) provides a great example of how to have a button start a new activity.

Key information from Mkyong's post:

In the activity where you want the button place the following, or if you already have a button give it an id, or if you've done all of this move onto the next step.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1" <!-- Id of your button -->
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me to another screen" />
```

Your main activity (or the activity where your button is on should contain the following:

```
package com.mkyong.android; // Name of package, change if necessary

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // ID of your button, change if necessary

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class); // Name of second activity's class, change if necessary
                            startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });

    }
```

That's it, as long as you have have a class set up for your second activity or XML then you do not need to go any further. If you do not have a class for your second activity create one and place in the following code:

```
package com.mkyong.android; //name of package, change if necessary 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2); // Name of second XML, change if necessary
    }

}
```

Seeing as you do not need complicated java to preform this action, using a simpler alternative as stated above would be better and would minimize issues.